# How to add code just below opening body tag in Genesis framework

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

We need to add two snippets of code, one right below the opening body tag, and the other right before the closing body tag. What is the best way to do this? I checked out the wp_enqueue_script, but it appears the content would be in the head section.

Answer (score 13):

Did you even open `header.php` and take a peek? You'll see `genesis_before()` called right after the opening `<body>` tag - follow the white rabbit and you get:

```
function genesis_before() { do_action('genesis_before'); }
```

And likewise for the footer. So...

```
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'im_a_lazy_copy_paster' );
add_action( 'genesis_after',  'im_a_lazy_copy_paster' );

function im_a_lazy_copy_paster() {
    if ( current_filter() == 'genesis_before' )
        echo '<script>party.start();</script>';
    else
        echo '<script>if ( cops.called() ) party.split();</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a plugin such as this to show all of the Genesis hooks: http://wordpress.org/plugins/genesis-visual-hook-guide/. This will allow you to quickly find the right hook to modify to do this.
Then modify the hook in the functions file.
You can also use a plugin which allows you to easily modify hooks through the wp-admin: http://www.studiopress.com/plugins/simple-hooks

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. `wp_enqueue_script` takes a parameter called in_footer which defines whether your script should be loaded before page content or at the end of the page body.

> **$in_footer**: (boolean) (optional) Normally scripts are placed in the `<head>` section. If this parameter is true the script is placed at the bottom of the `<body>`. This requires the theme to have the `wp_footer()` hook in the appropriate place. Note that you have to enqueue your script before `wp_head` is run, even if it will be placed in the footer. Default: `false`

Here is the reference on codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 0):

1. After the opening body tag.

   ```
   add_action( 'genesis_before', 'my_genesis_script' );

   function my_genesis_script() {

   if ( current_filter() == 'genesis_before' )

   echo '<script>parties.over();</script>';

   }
   ```

Structural Action Hooks

genesis_before: This hook executes immediately after the opening tag in the document source.

1. Before the closing body tag:

You can add the script to the Genesis > Theme Settings > Header and Footer scripts and enter your script you would like output to wp_footer().

The wp_footer() hook executes immediately before the closing  tag in the document source.

Comment: Brad as far as I'm aware, you can drop the `current_filter()` check. In this case, unless you have conditionals inside your `my_genesis_script()` function, checking if the filter is attached to the hook you're hooking into is unnecessary inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

An update for GenesisWP 3.3.1

Go to header.php

```
?>
</head>
<?php
genesis_markup(
    [
        'open'    => '<body %s>',
        'context' => 'body',
    ]
);

if ( function_exists( 'wp_body_open' ) ) {
    wp_body_open();
}

echo '<script>parties.over();</script>';

/**
 * Fires immediately after the `wp_body_open` action hook.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
do_action( 'genesis_before' )
```